# is it possible to have intellisence inside a script (.ps1) of PowerShell classes defined in a seperate module (.psm1) by the <using module> statement?

Tags: powershell, oop, visual-studio-code, module, intellisense

**Given:**

- PowerShell 5.1
- Visual Studio Code
- coding in OOP style with classes
- A module  with classes (psm1 file). I.e. class: [yyy]
- A script file using module  (ps1 file), by using statement:

**When:**

- Opening the script file
- Typing the 1st chars of a class name : i.e. [y

**Then:**

The intellisense feature does NOT show class yyy. It is not discovered at all..

Although the script works perfectly fine (creating objects based on defined class yyy), it is a hassle to  open the module file each time you need to look up the defined classes and its methods/properties...

Am i doing something wrong here or is it not (yet) supported by VSC?

Comment: You're not doing something wrong, there's a long list of filed issues on GitHub WRT making the edidting and testing experience with classes nicer

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for reacting and your answer. Good to know for sure that it is unfortunately not supported yet. I hope this will be addressed in the near future because it is kind of a fundamental feature for applying OOP in a proper fashion.